# How to check if wi-fi has internet in the flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity

How to check if connected wi-fi network has internet in the flutter app, when I use `connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi` from connectivity 3.0.6 package, it returns true, but the upcoming functionalities won't work if I disabled the wi-fi data connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the connection to a web page to make sure you have an internet connection, something like this :

```
  checkConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          con = true;
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        con = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

that's work for me good luck.